# Discrete Event simulation generates different results in windows and linux

Tags: c++, linux, random, simulation

I am doing a m/m/2/2 discrete event simulation. The result is same as the theoretical value, which means the program is correct (in Ubuntu, g++). However, when I tested the code again in windows (visual studio), the result is only correct when number of trials is less than 10000. I debugged for a very long time and finally find I have to use `(double) rand() / ( RAND_MAX + 1 )` rather than just `(double) rand() / RAND_MAX`.

Why is that? Do these two compiler generate random in different ways?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include "iomanip"
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define TRIAL_NUM 10000000

//structure that represent a customer
struct cust
{
int cust_id;
double arrival_time;
double depart_time;
};

//uniform random generator
double uniRand()
{
    return (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
}

//exponential random generator
double expRand(double lam)
{
double u,x;
u=uniRand();
x=(-1/lam)*log(1-u);
return(x);
}

int main()
{
    //seed the random generator
srand (time(NULL));                   
//queue that hold all customers
std::queue<cust*> customers;
double lam = 0, mu = 0;
bool showStatus = false;
cout<<"M/M/1/1 Discrete Event Simulation with "<<TRIAL_NUM<<" customers\n"<<" Please spacify the value of lambda:";
cin>>lam;
while(lam<= 0)
{
    cout<<"lambda value must be a positive number, try again:";
    cin>>lam;
}
cout<<"Please specify the value of mu:";
cin>>mu;
while(mu<= 0)
{
    cout<<"lambda value must be a positive number, try again:";
    cin>>mu;
}
cout<<"Show status for each customer? (y/n)";
char show;
cin>>show;
while( tolower(show) != 'y' && tolower(show) != 'n')
{
    cout<<"Invalid input, try again:";
    cin>>show;
}
if ( tolower(show) =='y' )
{
    showStatus = true;
}

//Generating all arrival time, service time for all customers
double temp_time = 1;
cust* temp;
for (int i = 1; i <= TRIAL_NUM; ++i)
{
    temp= new cust;
    temp -> arrival_time = temp_time + expRand(lam);
    temp_time = temp->arrival_time;
    temp->depart_time = temp->arrival_time + expRand(mu);
    temp->cust_id = i;
    customers.push(temp);
}

//Blocking customer count
double block = 0;
bool blockFlag = false;
temp = customers.front();
double server1 = 0, server2 = 0; 

//perform simulation
while( !customers.empty())
{
    if ( server1 < temp->arrival_time)
    {
        server1 = temp->depart_time;
    }
    else if ( server2 < temp->arrival_time)
    {
        server2 = temp->depart_time;
    }
    else
    {
        block++;
        blockFlag = true;
    }
    if (showStatus)
    {
        cout<<"Customer "<<temp->cust_id<<"\tarrived at:"<<temp->arrival_time<<"\tservice time:"<<temp->depart_time<<"\tstatus:";
        if (blockFlag)
        {   
            cout<<"Blocked"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Served"<<endl;
        }
    }
        customers.pop();
        if (!customers.empty())
        {
            temp = customers.front();
        }
        blockFlag = false;
}
cout<<"Blocking probability is: "<<block/TRIAL_NUM<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't use rand().  It will give different results on different compilers and the results will be dreadful.  For example, print rand() % 2 for the first 20 values it generates on windows and boggle at the output ... C++ has a number of alternatives, and std::mt19937 would probably suite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(double) rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1)` is a dangerous expression.

If, as it often happens, `RAND_MAX` is equal to `INT_MAX` then `RAND_MAX + 1` is an overflow and undefined behaviour (it usually results in `INT_MIN` but this is not guaranteed by any specification).

In Visual C++ `RAND_MAX` is 32767 and you haven't this problem (but 32767 is a small value it "starts cycling" quite quickly).

Anyway I think that the real problem is here:

```
u = uniRand();
x = (-1 / lam) * log(1 - u);
```

When `uniRand()` is defined as `(double) rand() / RAND_MAX` it produces values in the range:

```
0.0 <= uniRand() <= 1.0
```

and when the value is equal to 1.0 you have a [*pole error*](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP32-C.+Prevent+or+detect+domain+and+range+errors+in+math+functions) in your `log(1-u)`. This will happen more frequently with Visual C++ because of the small value of `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation is very helpful! So what am I supposed to do to make the code work in both platforms and also avoid the "dangerous expression"?

Comment: I would stay with the `(double) rand() / RAND_MAX` expression, checking `x = (-1 / lam) * log(1 - u);` to avoid domain error (`lam` or `1-u` near 0.0). Also check memory allocation (you're allocating memory in `temp = new cust;` but not releasing it).

Comment: Another possible solution is to grab a copy of [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/eversions.html) and use the [0,1) variant of the generator.